# How to manually edit gitolite config file (running with redmine)

Tags: redmine, gitolite

Say I want to manually edit the configuration files of gitolite (`conf/gitolite.conf` and add keys). What is the correct way to do so?

Logged as git on the server, I have tried to clone `git@localhost:gitolite-admin`, perform my changes, then push.

Note that I have used a `--force` and non-fast forward edits (rebase to rewrite history). However, the push seems to worked, since a new clone checkout include my changes. But, I can not observe any changement from outside. I am pretty confident in my edits and would know if I miss a step (such as a daemon to restart or anything else...).

Comment: Can you try a `gitolite setup` command, to see if those changes are interpreted correctly by gitolite? (assuming gitolite V3 here)